# Orderby Not working after grouping items

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a function that's main goal to group items by id, count them and finally order them by count.

```
var Db = list.Select(x => new
         {
             Id = x
         });

var groups = Db.GroupBy(g => new { Id = g.Id })
               .Select(g => new
               {
                   Id = g.Key.Id,
                   Cnt = g.Count()
               }).Distinct().OrderBy(g => g.Cnt).ToList();
```

Do you have any idea, where the error might be? It is not ordering. I have a bunch of low counts at first then it becomes random.

'list' is a one-dimensional list with many duplicated Ids (string) .

This is the output its giving out: ( I do not understand why there's duplicates in the ID since I'm only grouping by one key).

> Link to output : https://pastebin.com/NjqJ4Aub

Comment: It *should* work. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Paste the current result and the result you want.

Comment: Post sample data in the query. Also, your `Db` definition seems suspect... the `Select` serves no real purpose.